# Performance Issue in for Loop?

Tags: c#

Consider the following program,

```
     List<string> l_lstRawData = new List<string>();
     ........
     ........
```

Now the l_lstRawData is filled with data,for example,

```
    l_lstRawData[0] = "11111101101010................................0000011101010101";
    l_lstRawData[1] = "11111101111111...............................0000011101010101";
    l_lstRawData[2] = "11111101101010................................0000011101010101";
    l_lstRawData[3] = "11100001101010................................0000011101010101";
    l_lstRawData[4] = "11000101101010................................0000011101010101";
    l_lstRawData[5] = "11111101101010................................0000011101010101";
```

Now i want the result 
        List l_lstResultData = new List();

```
    l_lstResultData [0] = "111111";
    l_lstResultData [1] = "111111";
    l_lstResultData [2] = "111101";
    l_lstResultData [3] = "111001";
    l_lstResultData [4] = "111001";
```

This is the code i am using,
**The Length of l_lstRawData is equal to each individual element in l_lstRawData**

```
    string l_strTempData  = "";
    for(int l_nData;l_nData< l_lstRawData.Length;l_nData++)
    {
         l_strTempData  = "";
         for(int l_nItem = 0;l_nItem< l_lstRawData.Length;l_nItem++)
         {
             l_strTempData += l_lstRawData[**l_nData**].ToString();   
         }      
         l_lstResultData.Add(l_strTempData );
    }
```

It Takes long time since the each item of l_lstRawData Length is more than 60,000.....
Is it possible using any other method?

If u have any queries plz revert back me.

Comment: Why are you encoding bits as a string? there may be a much better way at doing what you are trying to do that will be much faster. Also what is the goal of the for loop, bcause if I am understanding it right, right now all it does is combine all of the items in l_listRawData in to one string and adds it to l_lstResultData, then it does that l_listRawData times.

Comment: You're not using `l_nData` within the loop, so I believe your code is fatally flawed to start with, regardless of performance.

Comment: Also, one of your input strings is shorter than the others... how would you expect it to handle that?

Comment: `throw new VariableNamingConventionUnreadableException()`

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain ,@:Jon Skeet sorry , i wrongly typed the code.just now i changed it.plz go through it and tell me the solution

Comment: @user374191, Your code now puts the same string l_lstRawData.Length times in to each element of the result list, however this time each result line will be different. I do not see what the goal of this loop is other than to make really long strings.

Comment: Why do you have the second loop if you aren't using l_nItem?

Answer (score 6):

Oh boy, yeah, string concatenation is really slow. You should consider using the StringBuilder class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: It's not the for loop itself, no. It's what you are doing in the loop :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could start by using stringbuilder instead of string concatenation.

Second, what you are doing in the loop can be done with a very fast substring method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder! Strings are immuatable (they don't change). Every time you concatenate a string, the run-time creates a NEW string with the new contents, and gives the older version of garbage collection. When you do this in loop, this can become a significant problem. Use StringBuilder instead and you'll see a dramatic difference.